# Full name and Meanings of prefix "g", "W", "f", "m" in GCC options

Tags: gcc

In GCC, there are many options begin with "g", "W", "f" or "m".

- "g": -glevel -ggdb
- "W": -Wa, -Wl, -Wall
- "f": -fno-access-control, -fno-rtti
- "m": -masm

I don't know the full names and meanings of "g", "W", "f", "m".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- G → GCC debugging (enables debugging messages)
- W → warning (`w` disables all warning messages, `Wall` enables all warnings)
- F → function (deals with functions that are treated by the compiler)
- M → make (outputs a tree map of the source file and all included file, kind of a Makefile).

You should look at [this page](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/comopts.html) which is very useful.